# SMTP: when sending a linux command, does it execute on the server side or client side?

Tags: smtp

I'm learning SMTP and I would like to know: when I send a command to a SMTP server, for instance "touch ~/file.txt", will the file be created on the server side or on my machine ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Neither. SMTP is an email transfer protocol only, and does not support running arbitrary commands on either side. (You might be confusing it with SSH or UUCP?)

That said, in general, if you send a command to a server, it'd be natural for it to only affect the server. In most cases, if the server was somehow able to control the client, it would be considered a security hole.